# how Symfony2 cache my file app_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony

There is no `phpinfo();` in my app_dev.php, view in the web is OK (no phpinfo) and I type `phpinfo();` in app_dev.php, view the web, but it's still no phpinfo, and no effect, and i still refresh the web, about few minutes (maybe many times refreshing), it works, (yes phpinfo is showing in the web)

This is my code:

```
phpinfo();
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Why? I'm confused. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This can be due to a number of reasons, from Opcode caching by PHP, to saving/synchronisation to the filesystem that the webserver reads.

Comment: glade to see u, i have stopped Opcache, and every thing OK. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case - your code is working. I think its not a symfony issue.
But at all you can run phpinfo with default symfony profile toolbar.
Look at here: [image]

Comment: I know this is a toobar where can see that. i am just  curious. Why ur ok, but mine cached. Maybe my Nginx issue?

Comment: I have a default nginx and php-fpm configuration. Maybe it is file writing issue. Are you working with file on local machine? Maybe your IDE save changes with some delay?

Comment: I change my IDE to notepad++ from PhpStorm . And doesn't work, even though clean cache folder,OM

Comment: But it's OK suddenly when i restart my php-cgi that's version is php7,

Comment: Oh, I'm glad that everything turned. Thanks for your response about your issue.

Comment: OK! thank you ! the problem is opcache, when i close it ,everything is all ok.